# Formatting Text File in XML with tags missing on start of the element

Tags: xml

I have a text file with XML format and I am using Notepad++ to apply the proper tags but I don't know how to apply the tags on start of elements which are unique numbers and dates.
eg.

```
10000 2014-01-10 <1> Hello </1>
10001 2014-01-31 <1> Hey </1>
```

The solution I need to format the above two elements like

```
<0 data="10000 2014-01-10"> <1> Hello </1> </0>
<0 data="10001 2014-01-31"> <1> Hey </1> </0>
```

There are over 20000 records for which I need the formatting. How would I do that ?

Comment: Use a language that supports file IO and regular expressions.  Ruby, Java, bash, etc.

Comment: OK, with the rephrased question: What you have, and what you want, are both well formed XML Document Fragments. Neither is a well formed XML Document unless you wrap another element around the whole thing.

So you can either use a tool which specifically supports DocumentFragments, or add that outer element, or do pure text-based manipulation of the file (as others have suggested, using regex or equivalent pattern-match-and-replace).

Comment: I have around 20000 elements which have tags in between them which can be separated and can be used for mapping the data within. But at the start I have Id & date for which I need a unique starting tag like - <pat id ="ID Date"> and closing tag as </pat>. How can we find those ID & date and place the <pat id="ID Date> at the start? I am using Notepad ++ 5.9.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a Regex to achieve this case.

Mentioned below is the `Find and Replace` method using Regex:

**Regex:** `(.*)(<1>(.*)</1>)`

**Replace With:** `<0 data="$1">$2</0>`

[image: Find N Replace]

Comment: Here is what I have 103305 2004-07-21 <CL><CL0><0>Notes: order trial lenses</0><3>PC Tor</3><4>PC</4><5>8.80</5><6>8.80</6><9>-1.00 -0.75x080</9><10>-1.50</10><i1>2</i1><i2>2</i2></CL0></CL>        What is needed is <Pat id = "103305 2004-07-21"> <CL><CL0><0>Notes: order trial lenses</0><3>PC Tor</3><4>PC</4><5>8.80</5><6>8.80</6><9>-1.00 -0.75x080</9><10>-1.50</10><i1>2</i1><i2>2</i2></CL0></CL> </Pat>